# iTextSharp - Creating header/margins results in inconsistent page coordinates

Tags: c#, itext

Why does the following code affect a page's ability to find its top, bottom, right and left?

Before applying it, `reader.GetCropBox(i).GetLeft(0)` and `reader.GetPageSize(i).GetLeft(0)` return the far left point of every page in an assorted set. After applying it, `GetLeft(0)` is the far left on some pages and on others the left most point AFTER the margin ends.

I'm trying to create a header on any given set of preexisting pages (ie, create white space and then put text in it)

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(outputPdfPath2, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(outputPdfPath))
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
            {
                int n = reader.NumberOfPages;

                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    //iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSize(i);
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetCropBox(i);

                    //////////
                    // Create Margin
                    float marginTop = 160;
                    float marginBottom = 160;
                    float marginLeft = 160;
                    float marginRight = 160;

                    float width = size.Width + marginLeft + marginRight;  // 8.5f * 72;
                    float height = size.Height + marginTop + marginBottom; // 11f * 72;
                    float tolerance = 1f;

                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(i);
                    float widthToAdd = width - cropBox.Width;
                    float heightToAdd = height - cropBox.Height;
                    if (Math.Abs(widthToAdd) > tolerance || Math.Abs(heightToAdd) > tolerance) 
                    {
                        float[] newBoxValues = new float[] { 
                            cropBox.Left    - marginLeft,  // widthToAdd  / 2,
                            cropBox.Bottom  - marginBottom,// heightToAdd / 2,
                            cropBox.Right   + marginRight, // widthToAdd  / 2,
                            cropBox.Top     + marginTop    // heightToAdd / 2
                        };
                        PdfArray newBox = new PdfArray(newBoxValues);

                        PdfDictionary pDict = reader.GetPageN(i);
                        pDict.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, newBox);
                        pDict.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, newBox);
                    }
                    //////////
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

The original code is borrowed from the answer given here: [How to resize existing pdf page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375150/how-to-resize-existing-pdf-page-size)

Comment: Can you share a PDF that in combination with your code illustrates the issue?

Comment: I found the problem... some pages are rotated, which you wouldn't know until you realise both GetPageSize and GetCropBox are returning a rotation that isn't the rotation...